# Reduce Selected Image File to 700 pixel via Apple Quick Action

Tags: macos, automation, automator, macos-monterey

I'm new Apple Automator scripting, I create a new Document type (Quick Action)
named, **reduceTo700**

I have it **Run Shell Script**

```
for f in "$@"
do
  /usr/bin/sips -Z 700 "$f" --out "${f%.*}.700px.jpg"
  /usr/bin/pbcopy < "${f%.*}.700px.jpg"
done
```

[image]

The logs show green, but I see no file generated.

[image]

How can I get this to work ?

Comment: Is it your intention to create intermediate files on disk? Is it your intention to copy multiple JPEGs to your clipboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the following:

- you don't really want to retain any *"on disk"* output files, and
- you don't really want to copy multiple files to the clipboard

you can use this:

```
# Pick up and use just first filename received
f="$1"

# Make temp file to ensure PNG and to ensure we can remove at end 
tmp="$(/usr/bin/mktemp /tmp/sipsZ700-XXXXXX).png"

# Resize
/usr/bin/sips -Z 700 "$f" -s format png --out "$tmp"

# Tell Finder to put it on pasteboard
osascript <<EOF
tell app "Finder" to set the clipboard to (read ( POSIX file "$tmp" ) as {«class PNGf»})
EOF

# Clean up
rm "$tmp"
```

I hard-coded PNG format because it can support 8/16-bit images and also transparency, so it is arguably more flexible than JPEG.

Comment: Let me try this out, thanks for your help!

Comment: Your codes work perfectly in first try! Thank-you so much!.

Comment: May I know the reason it has to be PNG ? YOu said, "# Make temp file to ensure PNG ..."

Comment: Can you also teach me how to blur image ? https://stackoverflow.com/q/76174235/4480164

Comment: It's not that it *has* to be PNG, it just has to be *something definite* so that all the tools know what format they are targeting. I chose PNG because it can do more than JPEG - including transparency and 16-bit. It may even be possible to use TIFF which is even more flexible.