# Blur image 50% when drop into a folder

Tags: bash, macos, shell, automation, automator

I have a bash script, connect to folder action in Automator. When I drop an image into `~/Desktop/Blur` folder, it should generate the blur version into that directory.

## I've tried

```
#!/bin/bash

# Change to the desktop directory
cd ~/Desktop/Blur

# Get the input filename
input_file="$1"

# Get the directory and base name of the input file
input_dir=$(dirname "$input_file")
input_base=$(basename "$input_file")

# Set the output filename
output_file="${input_dir}/blurred_${input_base}"

# Blur the image and save the result
convert "$input_file" -blur 0x8 "$output_file"

# Show an alert when done
osascript -e 'display notification "Image successfully blurred" with title "Blurring Complete"'
```

---

## I've ran

it 10 times now and I saw nothing generate, but I kept seeing the alert success.

## Steps

This is how I set it up

[image]

Can someone pls help ?

Comment: Does your input_file contains path relative to `~/Desktop/Blur`?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to set your `PATH` at the top of the script so that `bash` can find `convert`.

If `convert` works in your Terminal, go to Terminal and run:

```
type convert
/opt/homebrew/bin/convert
```

Then you will get its full path, and you can use that in your script, either explicitly on every invocation with something like:

```
/opt/homebrew/bin/convert  "$input_file" -blur 0x8 "$output_file"
```

or by setting the PATH at the top:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/homebrew/bin
```

which will allow you to just use:

```
convert  "$input_file" -blur 0x8 "$output_file"
```